# why can't I install Tor browser?

Tags: windows, firefox

I can download the browser, but nothing happens when I click on it. Well, actually I see the Aero graphic (little blue circle) for a brief instant, then nothing. I can't get anything out of the downloaded file.

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows, Mac, Linux? Where did you download the browser from?

Comment: I am running Vista Home Premium. I downloaded the browser from the official site and also from CNET; the icon that ended up on my desktop was identical in both cases and the same file size. But when I clicked on it, nothing happened. Normally I'm able to download things and install them, I don't know any reason why I couldn't in this case

Comment: Do you know how to run commands from inside `cmd` (i.e. from the command line)? If so, can you try running the executable from there? It will hopefully output some logs. Alternatively, another thing to try would be to temporarily disable any firewalls or antivirus programs you have running. (Or, better still, configure them to allow Tor.)

Comment: Actually, I have seen that little black box but I don't know anything about using it. As far as antivirus goes, I haven't had to disable anything for any of the other programs I have downloaded and installed. If you can tell me what to do I'll try it

Comment: I am having the same problem, and this is the 4th version it has happened with (5.0.3, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.5). I have disabled my security software, no change. I have tried to run as administrator, no change. I am also running Vista Home Premium. I downloaded the installer from the Tor site.

Comment: Exactly same problem. It seems to open, but nothing happens

Comment: hey bro dont know if you solved the problem yet all you need to do is go inbto the properties of the file asnd select compatabilty ( forwhat system your running ) and you should be good to go

Comment: ..same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of the downloaded file for tor browser and click the tab "unblock" to allow installation for windows vista home.

Comment: **N.B.** Do *not* continue to use Windows Vista! It is no longer supported by Microsoft and won't receive security updates [as of last month](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet).